# Managing service urls in mobile (phonegap) apps

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I wrote a phonegap / jQuery mobile app which runs fun in the iphone emulator. My app is getting data from a remote host. At the moment I have ajax requests to "localhost:8080" across my code.

I know, this is not good. I would like to change it.

What is the best practice for URLs in mobile webapps?

I mean, can I differ somehow on "build time" which url to use? Should i do something like "if emu the use localhost"?

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently deployed a mobile web app which makes various calls to a remote host. For me, the simplest solution was to use relative URIs for all the remote calls I was making, and employ a local reverse-proxy to direct the request to the appropriate server (I was targetting different servers in development vs. production).

I developed and tested this app locally, using the built-in Apache server in OS X, so configuring this was easy (for local web previews in OS X you modify the `<USER_NAME>.conf` file found in `/etc/apache2/users`).

YMMV, but this was a no-brainer for me in that no code needed to be modified.

Comment: Sorry, need to ask: you mean, you sent the request to the "real" url, but configured your osx to handle this url itself? I am not sure about the relative URLs- my HMTL files are stored locally on the iphone, so I don't think it will work out with relative URLs?

Comment: Yes. For example, I would define something like this (relative) URL in my code: `/ajax/somecall.aspx`, and that would then become `http://192.168.x.x/ajax/somecall.aspx` because I'm running locally (192.168.x.x is your local machine). My local Apache config then uses proxy directives to "translate" `/ajax/` to `http://someserver.com/ajax/`

Comment: And how is it supposed to work when the html page is installed as app on the iphone? Then there is no Apache which can act as proxy

Comment: If you need to access different resources from an app depending on its dev / production status, I'd say you need to build in some kind of configuration module to store any URIs you require, and have the app pull the URIs from there. That's how I'd do it, but I've not built anything in PhoneGap, so maybe there's another convention for that.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need. Thanks for all your time

Comment: No problem. I see that PhoneGap has a `localStorage` layer (see the `Storage` API) for key/value pairs, which works in the same way as the API in decent web browsers, so that looks to be the obvious place for settings like this.

Comment: I will consider that. Maybe I can have a "special storage" for a specific build. I will digg through the deployment docs (if any) and the storage docs. The latter one i need for another feature, this time is not lost. Thanks for your help. Even when I didn't get a "ready to use" solution your help is so appreciated I vote your answer up now. Cheers!